# Android Studio: Discrepency between Gradle versions mentioned in Gradle file and File > Project Structure > Project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After the update of Android Studio to version 2.3.1, Android Studio displayed an alert recommending an upgrade of Gradle from 2.3.1 to 3.3. I clicked 'yes' and it launched a Synch process.

But surprisingly, the Gradle version mentioned in the Gradle file did not change. In my Gradle file, I still have:

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'      
    }
```

But I have got in the File > Project Structure > Project menu in Android Studio:

[image]

Why do I have a Gradle version of 3.3 in this window and 2.3.1 in my Gradle file ?

I also see in this window that the 'Android Plugin Version' is '2.3.1'. Is there any link between this 'Android Plugin Version' and com.android.tools.build:gradle version which is also 2.3.1 ?

Should I set 3.3 for these three fields ? ( 1: Gradle Version (setup window), 2: Android Plugin Version (setup window), 3: com.android.tools.build:gradle (Gradle file))

Thanks for your explanations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Plugin Version (setup window) and com.android.tools.build:gradle (Gradle file) are same thing and Gradle version mentioned in the

> Project/gradle/wrapper/graddle-wrapper.properties

file as

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```